# Marketing Cloud Import Definition through SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import

I am trying to integrate with Marketing Cloud from Mulesoft and want to upload data from File to Data Extension. There is Import Definition Activity using SOAP API explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_an_import_definition.htm) in documentation. However, there is no clear explanation how to specify custom delimiter.
Also, when I do import for the data enclosed in double quotes, it is not ignoring the double quotes.

Can someone please help me with how to specify these 2 condition in SOAP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you reviewed the [WSDL](https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl) for ImportDefinition? If you're looking for details about properties, that's what actually is available. That's where I look if the [SOAP Object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/importdefinition.htm) isn't enough.

You specify the delimiter for your file with the `Delimiter` property.

I know `csv` and `tab` are valid values.

I'd expect `|` would also work since it's valid in the platform.

For the double-quote question, I'd experiment with setting the `StandardQuotedStrings` property.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom delimiter you have to use both Delimiter and FileType equals to "Other":

```
[...]
      <FieldMappingType>InferFromColumnHeadings</FieldMappingType>
      <FileSpec>%%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv</FileSpec>
      <FileType>Other</FileType>
      <Delimiter>|</Delimiter>
[...]
```